# Facebook extended permission grant by user

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to know if user has granted extended permission requested by application. I use java at back end, and login and facebook registration is handled by socialauth api. I want to publish feed to user's timeline.
Javascript is unable to hit the url because it doesn't have access token for facebook communication.
Can this thing be done without using any client facebook java api?

Answer (score 0):

Get [/me/permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/permissions) from the Graph API, in which ever way you like.

Comment: This doesn't help, as access token is with java and I don't want to use a client api for this purpose only. I want to figure out a way by url.

Comment: You have to use an access token, otherwise there’s no way of getting that data.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of a SignInAdapter, use the Connection object injected into the signIn(...) method to generate a facebook object and then use can use the userOperations object to get related permissions. The following code sample can help:

```
    Facebook facebook = (Facebook) connection.getApi();
    facebook.userOperations().getUserPermissions().stream().forEach(x -> log.info("Permission {}: {}", x.getName(), x.getStatus()));
```

I know this question is old but this answer might help anyone starting out. This is done based on the assumption that you are using spring-social-facebook.